# Json.document inside a measure

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Is it possible to use `Json.Document(Web.content("some rest service"))` inside a measurement in power bi?

I need get some data that dynamically changing from the service.

So in more detail i want to have a measure that calculates base on what on time like cumulative sums(i can do this easily) and then i need to feed this data to the service which will return a record that i can read and return one field of this json data returned from service.

is there anything i can do?

Comment: Unless you can set up a DirectQuery to the source, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: what do you mean directQuery to the source?

Comment: you mean the normal get data ? this is placing a fixed table in powerbi

Comment: When you use directQuery you do not place a fixed table in powerbi, I have to agree with Alex, I do not think it is possible

Comment: Best to create an Azure Automate or Azure Function, to get then dump the data to a location, then use Power BI to read from that location using the report refresh setting to update the dataset